# What are the advantages of using "new style" Cassandra paging state over "old style" token functions?

Tags: cassandra

I understand that there are two ways of iterating over a large result set in Cassandra:

1. Querying explicitly with tokens, as discussed in this article on "[Displaying rows from an unordered partitioner with the TOKEN function](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useToken.html)". This appears to have been the only way of doing things prior to Cassandra 2.0.
2. Using "[paging state](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/paging/)".

Paging state appears to be the suggested way of doing things these days, but doing it the old `token` way still *works*.

Aside from it being the blessed way of doing things, which is of course a type of advantage, I'd love to understand what are the particular advantages of using the "new" method over the "old"? Is there a reason I should *not* use `token` in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of paging or tokens is really depending on your requirements, and technical abilities. From my point of view, use of paging is good for fetching of data from big partition, or when you have not so much data in table, so you can use `select * from table`.

But if you have multiple servers in cluster, and big amounts of data, use of `token` will allow you to read data from specific servers (if you set routing key correctly), and in parallel (Spark Cassandra Connector uses `token` exactly for this reason) - this is big advantage over use of paging where you're using one coordinator node that needs to go to other nodes for data that it doesn't have.  But for some people, it's not really easy to implement, because you need to cover edge cases, like, when token range doesn't start exactly at minimum value. I have [example in Java](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java) how to do it if you need.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's a great explanation  The pointers to the Spark Cassandra Connector and the example file are really useful. I also realized there's another ease-of-use-benefit to using paging state in simple cases: It's awkward to page through large _single partitions_ wiith `token` but paging state deals with this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alex this answer, I will add that when you do that the old school(with tokens), you have the hand on your tokens, this mean that if you are dealing with a big amount of data, that you can save your check points for example, that you can handle well restart after failure, or just pausing your job for example, or also to launch multi-threading jobs and separate teach worker data, the way spark workers deal with data for example are token based too.

The driver handle the paging automatically for you so you don't have to fetch pages with all the advantage of a native thing handled for you, but the use of token give you full hands on the way you are paginating with all the advantage that you can get from it(attacking a specific range, specific server)

I hope this helps !